# Geting a function variable in another function in a python class

Tags: python, function, class, variables

So I have this code

```
class createNewFile:
    def createNewFile(createFileEntry):
        string = StringVar()
        createFileEntry = Entry( CROW, textvariable = string)
        createFileEntry.pack()
        createFileEntry.focus_set()

    def saveNewFile(message):
        filename = createFileEntry.get()
        extention = filename
        target = open (extention, 'a')
        message = tkMessageBox.showinfo('What happened','Recived ' +getFileEntry+' as filename')


newFileButton = createNewFile()
newFileButton.createNewFile()
newFileButton.saveNewFile

newFileIcon = PhotoImage(file='icons/newFile.png')
createFileBtn = Button(toolbar, image = newFileIcon, command = newFileButton.createNewFile,relief='solid',background='white', border=0)
createFileBtn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=0,pady=0)

saveFileIcon = PhotoImage(file='icons/saveFile.png')
saveFileEntry = Button(toolbar,image = saveFileIcon, command = newFileButton.saveNewFile,relief='solid',background='white', border=0)
saveFileEntry.pack(side=LEFT, padx=0,pady=0)
```

and the idea is for the new file button to create a entry space to get the name and extension of the file, and the save button to write it.

I read here in stack overflow how to set up the class for you to be able to call a variable from one function to another, but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: indentation is wrong. The two functions inside the class must be indented for them to be part of the class. If this is not exactly the code you are working with, please copy it with the correct indentation.

Comment: Where is the indentation wrong?

Comment: Now it is ok. It was wrong in the first version.

Comment: Define "it didn't work". Include any errors too (in the question itself).

Answer (score 1):

Here in the code shown above you are only creating local instances of the variables, create class variables if you want to use across classes, try using this: -

```
class createNewFile:
    def createNewFile(self): 
        string = StringVar()
        self.createFileEntry = Entry( CROW, textvariable = string)
        self.createFileEntry.pack()
        self.createFileEntry.focus_set()  

    def saveNewFile(self, message):
        filename = self.createFileEntry.get()  
        extention = filename 
        target = open (extention, 'a')  
        message = tkMessageBox.showinfo('What happened','Recived ' +getFileEntry+' as filename')
```

Also, I am unable to find getFileEntry in the source code you have provided.  anything that you want to save in the class instance, save or edit it using self.variable_name. I hope I have answered your question.

Comment: Also, thanks, I had changed the variable name and forgot to do so in the message

Comment: I'm sure it's something really silly that I'm not seeing. The error is TypeError: createNewFile() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). My code for instancing it is the same as in the question

Comment: Oh, this is because of def createNewFile(self, createFileEntry),
Remove createFileEntry from the class definition, adding in edit, try removing it and running it.
It is because, the function accepts createFileEntry as a parameter, and you are passing no parameters while calling the function

Comment: So I did that, and it came back to the original error: NameError: global name 'createFileEntry' is not defined

Comment: @NamitSingal I think you want `self.createFileEntry.` on the two last lines of the `def createNewFile(self):` block

Comment: You can also click the checkmark next to the answer to indicate that it was correct. :)